# Is a nondescript shopping statistic a normal distribution?

Tags: statistics

Suppose we have a certain product for which you can count how many times it's been bought every week for an entire year. Suppose I made a graph where every index on the X axis illustrates how many products were purchased in a week, and the Y axis would indicate on the percentage of weeks in total that had that exact number of products purchased.

My question is whether or not this is a normal distribution and does it depend on the product in question?

Edit:
The statistic in question is collected from a single household over the course of a year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of products purchased in a week is a positive integer.  The normal distribution is a continuous distribution with positive density on the whole real line.  So the answer to your question, taken literally, is "no".  The real question, perhaps, is "can this be well approximated with a normal distribution?"  The answer to that is, "maybe".  It will  certainly depend on the product in question.  You should get a good approximation to a normal distribution in a case  where there are many potential customers, each potentially buying one of this product at a time, and demand is steady
throughout the year (so not a seasonal product, and not one that will 
have dramatic price fluctuations, and not one where a few big customers will buy a million of them once or twice a year).

EDIT:
For a single household that buys only a small number of this product each week, a normal distribution will almost certainly be a very bad fit.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Just to clarify my question - the people who purchase this product are always the same. That is, the statistic is actually collected from a single household over the course of a year. I should have probably mentioned this in my question...

Answer (score 0):

Without the addition that data is from a single household, the obvious way to model it is as a [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution). When the average amount of products purchased is large, this is closely approximated by the normal distribution. (The Poisson model might be weak if the purchases are correlated, but it's a good start.)

However, if we're talking about a single household, then we're no longer in the realms of statistics and probability, but in the realm of the shopping habits of this particular family - you'd need to ask the family, not a math forum.

I expect that for most families and products, the distribution will be very far from normal.